# How can I update a parentScope array when it changes in the childScope in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-watch

I have a main controller with a nested child controller

```
<div class='main' ng-controller='mainController'>
    <div class='search' ng-controller='searchController'>
        <input type='text' ng-model='keyword'>
        <button ng-click='search(keyword)'>Search!</button
    </div>
</div>
```

In my main controller, I attempt to create a main-scoped variable to store the results of a search.

```
var app = angular.module('mapApp', [])
    .controller('mainController', [
        '$scope', 
        '$searchFactory',
        ($scope, searchFactory)=>{

            $scope.results = [];

            $scope.$watchCollection('results', (newVal, oldVal)=>{
                console.log('results updated to, ', newVal);
            }, true);

        }]);
```

Then I try to update the main controller's `$scope.results` variable in my child controller.

```
 app.controller('searchController', ['$scope', 'searchFactory', ($scope, searchFactory)=>{
        $scope.search = function(keyword, type){
            let request = {
                location: $scope.location,
                radius: '500',
                type: type ? type : undefined,
                keyword: keyword
            };
            searchFactory.search(request, (result)=>{
                console.log('result from search was', result);
                $scope.results = result;
            });
        };
    }]);
```

My `$watch` function doesn't get invoked, which I believe is because the `$scope.results` is not being updated. I've tried using the three type of `$watch` functions, as illustrated by the [Angular Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope) under the **$scope.watch depths** section. I read [this article](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes) on switching to prototype inheritance style for scopes but I'm not sure it's the best way to solve my problem, because I'm not sure I'm going down the right path. Perhaps I should be using event emitters/broadcasters instead to achieve my desired effect?

How can I update a `results` variable in `searchController`'s parent scope (`mainController`) so that I can then have it accessible by siblings of `searchController`?

**EDIT/SOLVED** So, this is *really weird*, and if you can explain why this is the case, gold star for you.

Here is the mainController when the code *doesn't* work:

```
.controller('mainController', [
        '$scope', 
        'searchFactory', 
        ($scope,searchFactory)=>{
            $scope.searchData = {results:[]};

            $scope.setResults = function(newResults){
                $scope.searchData.results = newResults;
                console.log('new results is', $scope.searchData.results);
            };

            //this function doesn't invoke except on initiation
            $scope.$watch('searchData.results', (newVal, oldVal)=>{
                console.log('results updated to, ', newVal);
            }, true);

        }]);
```

Here is the mainController when the code *does* work:

```
.controller('mainController', [
        '$scope', 
        'searchFactory', 
        ($scope,searchFactory)=>{
            $scope.searchData = {results:[]};

            //comment out the evil console log and... it works??!!
            $scope.setResults = function(newResults){
                $scope.searchData.results = newResults;
                //console.log('new results is', $scope.searchData.results);
            };

            //this invokes now, because black magic? 
            $scope.$watch('searchData.results', (newVal, oldVal)=>{
                console.log('results updated to, ', newVal);
            }, true);

        }]);
```

Why...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `$scope.results = result;` sets a new results property on the child scope which shadows the results property of the parent.

To fix this problem, you can use an object to hold the results property:

```
$scope.searchData = {results: []};

$scope.$watchCollection('searchData.results', (newVal, oldVal)=>{
    console.log('results updated to, ', newVal);
}, true);
```

and then in your child controller set only this property:

```
$scope.searchData.results = result;
```

Comment: For some reason it's still not working. Am I setting results properly? In the `searchController`, I do `$scope.searchData.results = result` where `result` is a returned array from an http request

Comment: I feel like it may be something wrong with the watch function, as well, as the watch function would not invoke even when I was using a setter function: 

            `$scope.setResults = function(newResults){
                $scope.results = newResults;
                console.log('new results is', $scope.results);
            };`

Comment: Yea, even with the setter, the $watch function isn't invoking. Here's the exact syntax of it: `$scope.$watchCollection('searchData.results', (newVal, oldVal)=>{
                console.log('results updated to, ', newVal);
            }, true);`

Comment: Is the 'result from search was' message being logged? Can you try putting together a plunker demonstrating your problem?

Comment: I sort of solved it, let me know if you know why a console log causes it to break... I'll put up a plunkr if need be. I'll mark you as solved in a few more minutes I just want to see if anybody can tell me why a console log would break the watch function, cause that's just too weird. EDIT: result from search was... is being logged yes

Comment: Put up a plunkr if you want and I'll take a look

Comment: I'll pop back in my commit history and take a look, but the real issue was I wasn't calling $scope.digest in the controller that was updating. Again though I appreciate the help.